# Changing the gradient color of a layer polygon on conditions that depend on another layer on QG

Tags: qgis, layers

I hope the title is not too much convoluted.

[image]

I am using QGIS to interact two layers. The first layer is geometrical shapes representing contiguous counties. The second layer is given by calls to emergency services. I would like the first layer to change gradient color according to the count of emergency services within that county. Is it possible to do this through QGIS, or shall I aggregate these in an outside environment?

Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In QGIS, you can give the ploygons a new field based on the values of the points contained within them, then you can use symbology to symbolize.

**To join the attributes**

Go to `Vector > Data Management Tools > Join Attributes by Location`

In `Join to Features in` select your polygon layer

Under `Features they` select `contain`

In `By comparing to` select your point layer

In `Fields to add` select the fields you'd like to symbolize with the color gradient

Click `Run`

**To Symbolize**

Right click on the layer and hit `Properties`, navigate to the `Symbology` tab, and play around with the setting to find what you'd like.

If you need further assistance with color gradient symbology, I'd suggest just googling it, because that it something that will be very easy to find resources on.

Comment: fantastic help, thanks